# Carousel behind transparent cutout in PNG image

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation, banner, slick.js

Having issues with what I assumed would be a simple task, maybe just need another set of eyes.

We have a banner image and on the right side is a computer monitor. the "screen" has been cut out so that portion of the banner is transparent (.PNG).

I need to place a carousel **behind** the cutout image, so that it gives the impression that the carousel is "playing" on the screen.

Right now I am trying to do this with [Slick Carousel](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) but if anyone else has a recommendation for a better carousel that is also responsive I'm open.

http://codepen.io/tconroy/pen/ZYRaRd

Above is a codepen of what I have so far -- The main issue I am encountering is that the slides are in front of the image content (overlapping the image), when it should be behind the image content (playing behind the banner, and just visible through the transparent "gap" in the screen).

I've used placeholder images for the slides, however those are the actual dimensions of each image we will be using. The images should be "centered" in their slide, with the background color visible. (basically the images are being overlaid onto the colored slides).

**HTML**

```
<div class="inner-wrap">
  <header>
  <div class="contain-to-grid">
  <div class="inner-carousel-wrapper">
  <div class="inner-carousel">
    <div class="slide yellow">
      <img class="" src="http://lorempixel.com/350/347/sports" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="slide purple">
      <img class="" src="http://lorempixel.com/416/347/abstract" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="slide red">
      <img class="" src="http://lorempixel.com/381/346/city" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="slide blue">
      <img class="" src="http://lorempixel.com/338/346/transport" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="slide green">
      <img class="" src="http://lorempixel.com/343/347/nature" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="slide orange">
      <img class="" src="http://lorempixel.com/361/347/cats" alt="">
    </div>
  </div> <!-- .inner-carousel -->
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/HodKXD4.png">
</div> <!-- .inner-carousel-wrapper -->
  </div>
</header>
</div>
<section class="container">
  Notice how the "slides" above are overlapping the ipad square (bottom right of monitor)? The slides should appear "behind" the ipad.
</section>
```

**SCSS**

```
$lesson-blue:   #33B2E6;
$lesson-green:  #26B789;
$lesson-orange: #F58231;
$lesson-yellow: #FFD648;
$lesson-red:    #E43533;
$lesson-purple: #616373;

.inner-carousel-wrapper {
  background: black;
}

.inner-carousel {
  position: absolute;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 54.3%;
  margin-top: 6.0%;
  width: 45.7%;
  height: 76%;
}

.inner-carousel .slide {
  &.blue   {background: $lesson-blue; }
  &.green  {background: $lesson-green;}
  &.orange {background: $lesson-orange;}
  &.yellow {background: $lesson-yellow;}
  &.red    {background: $lesson-red;}
  &.purple   {background: $lesson-purple;}

  img {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 6%;
    width: 60%;
  }
}
```

**JS**

```
$('.inner-carousel').slick({
      accessibility: false,
      autoplay:      true,
      autoplaySpeed: 2500,
      arrows:        false,
      draggable:     false,
      slide:         '.slide'
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is an option for you or not, but you can assign an `id` to your background image, give it absolute positioning and then alter its z-index. Something like this should work:

HTML

```
<img id="bg" src="http://i.imgur.com/HodKXD4.png">
```

CSS

```
#bg {position:absolute;z-index:2;}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZYRaNE

Comment: position: relative; is enough, and may be more usable

Comment: Hi, for some reason your solution is appearing behind the bg image for me -- it works great in the fiddle, but when I move it over to my actual code it's entirely behind the bg image and not visible.. Any ideas?

Comment: @Prefix You may need to adjust the positioning so that the images line up with the "hole" in the background image.

Comment: @DrydenLong yeah I've done that, but nothing is showing through the background image -- it's like the image isn't transparent. If I adjust the positioning so that the slides are lower than the image, I can see it on the bottom, but I can't see it through the BG image cutout

Comment: @DrydenLong if I add `z-index: -1` to the BG image, it disappears, and I can see the slider. But anything above -1 and the slider is entirely hidden. weird!

Comment: Turns out something fishy happened with my image.  Your solution worked the best for me. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

A couple things together fix this:

```
.contain-to-grid {
    /* background: #333; */
}
.inner-carousel-wrapper {
    /* background: black; */
}
.inner-carousel {
    z-index: -1;
}
```

**[Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vErWMW)**

You'll need to adjust sizing/position a bit, but it should work otherwise.

Comment: This fixes part of the problem (need my designer to pump out new assets :p ) but Notice how the "slides" above are overlapping the ipad square (bottom left of monitor)? The slides should appear "behind" the ipad.

Comment: Ah. I can't actually see the right side as your design is so wide.

Comment: Sorry, typo. Meant bottom left of monitor :)

Comment: Now I get it. Back to the drawing board.

Comment: I've set background for `.contain-to-grid` and `.inner-carousel-wrapper` to `:none`, however now the slider seems to have vanished and the screen area is just white... Must be another bg property I'm missing somewhere...

Comment: seems to be the `.inner-carousel z-index: -1` which is causing it to vanish. I'm not too familiar with z-index positioning, could it be a background property is overriding it in the display stack?

Comment: `:none` isn't a valid property value. Was that a typo in your comment?

Comment: Obviously it works in the demo. Here's one updated with better position and sizing. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JoZMBM